# Why did Lyle say he "wanted to try" something he's been doing for years?

Tags: the-italian-job

In *The Italian Job*, there's a scene where the crew is discussing the plan on a rooftop balcony in LA.

> CHARLIE: I want audio surveillance on his phone.
>
> LYLE: Oh, yeah, **I been wanting to try something**. I crack into the phone company's remote monitoring system, and fool it into thinking there's a legal tap on the line. Just reroute the digital copies of the calls to our own listening post. **I been doing it to my ex for years.**

I don't understand the two statements in bold.

If Lyle has already been doing this to his ex **for years**, why would he say he's been "wanting to try it"? Hasn't he already tried (and succeeded) at it?

Comment: I noticed the edit that removed "The" from the movie title, but in this case, "The" is technically part of the title. Check IMDB to verify.

Comment: I think he's saying he wants to try it in an actual job knowing that the technique works based on his doing it to his ex-wife. Tapping his wife served as a developmental experiment and "proof of concept." You would never use a technique in a real job that you hadn't tested out some way. Should have been better phrased, though.

Comment: @LevenTrek Uh, the edit didn't actually *remove* the "The", it just put it into proper formatting.

Comment: @ScottyParker Sounds like you're onto an answer there. You might want to flesh it out into one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Funnily enough, I said something very similar at work this week:

> Given that we're starting a new project; I'm going to start using Autofac. I've been using it in personal projects for a while now, and I think it's a valuable addition to lower development complexity/time.

Lyle is essentially saying the same here:

> "I've been using it *personally* for some time and it's really useful. Now I want to try it *professionally*."